# How to cancel SoftLayer order for Block Storage?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I was finally able to use SoftLayer services API to order an Endurance block storage.  Now, the question is how can I cancel it using the API?
Which data that I need from the order that I need to use to cancel?
And what API do I use to cancel?

I have the SoftLayer_Billing_Order and SoftLayer_Billing_Item information.
For a Virtual server, from above info, a guestId or hardwareId is used to identify the server and use it to delete.  I don't get such data for the storage.  They are empty.

So how do I reference an endurance block storage that I provisioned?
And how do I cancel or delete it  using the SoftLayer Services APIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To cancel an Endurance Block Storage, execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/[billing_item_id]/cancelService
```

**Method:** GET

Reference: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelService

**Additional requests:**

How to get the **billing_item_id**?

Execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[network_storage_id]/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[id,username,billingItem.id]
```

**Method:** GET

Reference:http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getObject

How to get the **network_storage_id**?

Execute:

If we know the name assigned to the Endurance, we can use filters to get this specific item:
e.g. username: SL01SEL123456-1

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectFilter={"networkStorage":{ "username":{"operation":"SL01SEL123456-1"}}}
```

**Method:** GET

Reference: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage

Answer (score 1):

Basically to cancel a device in softlayer you need to cancel the billing item,
to cancel the billing item you can use these methods:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelItem
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/createObject

A endurance Blog storage is a Network storage object so to get the billing item you can use
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getBillingItem

and to get all network storages in your device you can use http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage

Regards