# How to create a volume in softlayer using rest api

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How to create a volume in softlayer using rest api
their is no option for create volume

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Curently, It is not possible to create volume in softlayer neither API nor Softlayer' Portal.

Regards

Comment: Power on soft layer server using rest API using JSON request

Comment: In order to power on you just need to call this method using the GET method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/powerOn

Comment: How to create 2 disk while provision using private image using rest

Comment: You need to use the placeOrder method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder, you need to send a container object to the method, in the container there is a attribute called imageTemplateId you need to specify the id of the template you want there e.g. see this container http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest. Then you just need to specify the prices of the items (disk ,ram,etc) you want in the order see this e.g. https://softlayer.github.io/rest/place_order/

Comment: Also this can help you to understand orders http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-3

Answer (score 0):

These examples may help you:

- Create `performance` and `endurance` storage:
  [API for Performance and Endurance storage(Block storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454059/api-for-performance-and-endurance-storageblock-storage)
- List `Network storage`:
  [How can we capture storage_Id while placing order for storage (either performance or endurance)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153864/how-can-we-capture-storage-id-while-placing-order-for-storage-either-performanc)
- Get `Network_Storage_id`:
  [How can we capture storage_Id while placing order for storage (either performance or endurance)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153864/how-can-we-capture-storage-id-while-placing-order-for-storage-either-performanc)
- Also to cancel`network storage`, please see:
  [How to cancel SoftLayer order for Block Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659910/how-to-cancel-softlayer-order-for-block-storage)

Regards.